# Getting js objects from browser console and Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm working on a new project, the client is a bank and I need to perform performance tests, I wanted to use jmeter as a main tool, but I found a problem, most of the pages ask for a token, so I need to catch token and set this to the next POST request in order to login and continue through the different page forms, the problem is that this token is generated by a javascript, so is not returned in any GET response body; I can just get it by console's browser, because this token is generated in a javascript object.

I've tried with postProcessor elements as regular expression extractor, JSR223 PostProcessor (I'm not a pro with) and finally with Webdriver Sampler, this last one is working, but I had to import some Java classes, did some modifications, etc; but I this is not an option, because if I perform the test with several virtual users the machine is going to run out of resources.

I was wondering if you have faced with something similar, if so, could you please make me a suggestion?, maybe perform tests with a different tool, framework...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend looking into the response more attentively as the token might be coming as a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or a [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), if this is the case you should be able to extract it using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) or [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) correspondingly.

If the token is generated via JavaScript code you can re-implement the logic using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and use [vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function in order to store the generated value into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). If you cannot come up with the relevant Groovy code - update your question with the JavaScript code snippet and most probably we'll be able to help you with converting it into Groovy and exposing to next Sampler(s)